# Decrypt SHA256 hash to original string?

Tags: hash, sha256

Is it possible to take an original hash value, and then decode it back to the original string?

`hash('sha256', $login_password_for_login)` gets me a hash, as shown below, but I'd like to go from the hash value back to the original string.

With `$login_password_for_login = 12345`, the `hash` function gives me this: 
 `5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf5a9c173cacfc5`

I'd like to be able to retrieve the original number or string that I had for the login password.  How do I reverse the hash and get that original string?

Comment: Hashes are one-way. They cannot be decrypted since they are not encrypted.

Answer (score 5):

You **don't** 'decrypt' the hashes because hashing is not encryption.

As for undoing the hash function to get the original string, there is no way to go from hash to original item, as hashing is a one-direction action. You can take an item and get a hash, but you can't take the hash and get the original item.

Make a note that hashes should NOT be confused with encryption; encryption is a different process where you can take an item, encrypt it with some type of key (either preshared or symmetric keys like PGP keys), and then later decrypt it.  Hashes do not work that way.

---

In comments, you indicate that you're trying to save a passcode in the database.  The problem is, you don't want someone who can breach the DB to be immediately be able to decrypt passcodes, which is why hashing is so attractive.

The idea, then, is that you would *consider* using salted hashes, storing only the salt on a per-user basis in the DB as its own record, and then store the salted hash of their original password string in the database.

Then, to verify a password is entered proper, get the salt from the DB, get the user input for a given password, and then using the salt from the DB, get the salted hash for that input.  Take that resultant hash and compare it to the salted hash stored in the DB.  If they match, you have a validated password; if they don't match, it's invalid.

This way, there's actually no *decryption* of any passwords readily doable, which means in a data breach situation of your site the passwords are not easily able to be retrieved.  (This doesn't rule out someone breaching your database, copying down the data, and trying to brute-force the passwords, but depending on what you enforce for password complexity and the effort a hacker wants to actually go through to get credentials, this is less likely to happen)

I'd write an example of this in a language I understand, but as you don't define what language you're working with, it's not going to be possible for me to write a useful example for you here.

That said, if you're working with PHP, you may find [this document on crackstation.net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) about doing secure salted password hashing properly; there's already PHP implementations to do this proper so you wouldn't have to write your own code, supposedly.

Comment: Then what I do for save password in database and retrieve it

Comment: @AbdulAli It helps when yuo state that's what your goal is.  The way I would do it is as follows: (1) use a salt on a per-user basis, and store the salt in the DB. (2) Do a salted sha256 hash on the original password and store the resultant hash. (3) For login checking, take the password entered, use the salt from the DB for that specific user, compare the resultant salted sha256 hash with the one you stored in the DB for the user.  There's very little chance of collisions that I know of with this method, and if there's a match of the two hashes being compared, then assume it's the right PW.

Comment: @AbdulAli That said, you ***really*** should be specifying that as the objective in your question, and your question should really be "How do I securely store passwords in a DB for a login system" or similar, and define what language you're trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

### Hashes cannot be decrypted, as they are not encryption.

Although the output of a hash function often looks similar to that of an encryption function, *hashing is actually an extremely lossy form of data compression.* When I say "extremely lossy", I mean "all of the original data is destroyed in order to get a fixed length." Since none of your original data remains, you cannot decrypt a hash.

That being said, ***hashes can be used to emulate encryption.*** What you do is that, when a person registers, you make a tuple containing the hashes of their username and password. Then, when somebody tries to login, you compare the hashes like this*:

```py
import hashlib
from login_info import logins # This is an array containing the tuples.

def hasher(string: str) -> bytes:
    stringer = bytes(string)
    return hashlib.sha256(stringer).hexdigest()

def login(username: str, password: str) -> int: # Returns 0 if login correct, else 1.
    user = hasher(username)
    pass = hasher(password)

    for i in range(len(logins)):
        if logins[i][0] == user:
            if logins[i][1] == pass:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
        else:
            return 1
```

* Nota Bene: I am using Python 3 for the example, as my PHP and Javascript are a little out of practice.

**EDIT:** On second thought, it is actually possible to (somewhat) decrypt a hash. Basically, you take the hash and then try every entry in the corresponding section of the hash table to see if it's right. This is why you should *always* salt password hashes.